# NGINX reverse proxy cannot find Hostname after 10 minutes

Tags: wordpress, curl, nginx, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean

I have a website on *www.mydomain.com* and would like to direct traffic via proxy to another server when the URL ends with */blog*. This other server runs a Wordpress blog and `WORDPRESS_URL` and `SITE_URL` both point to its IP address.

My current setup is, DNS points to *mydomain.com*, where nginx works as a reverse proxy. Any request is directed via `proxy_pass` to a web application running on *localhost:3000*, except the ones matching */blog*. For these requests I have in my NGINX conf, inside the single `server` block, the following:

```
location /blog {
  rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1 break;

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://<blog-ip>;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

The proxy works well and requests do go to the blog server, but page resources, like fonts and themes are not returned propertly due to CORS. I assume I have to change `WORDPRESS_URL` and `SITE_URL` to *www.mydomain.com/blog* and everything does function properly at first but, about 10 minutes after the URL changes, it stops working completely and *www.mydomain.com/blog* starts returning *Bad Gateway*.

The strangest part is, before the URL changes, `ping` and `curl` work just fine running from **mydomain** server:

```
$ ping <blog-ip> -W 2 -c 3
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.391/0.507/0.690/0.132 ms


$ curl -I <blog-ip>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

After *Bad Gateway* begins, `ping` still works:

```
$ ping <blog-ip> -W 2 -c 3
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.391/0.507/0.690/0.132 ms
```

but `curl` does not:

```
$ curl -Iv <blog-ip>
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying <blog-ip>...
* connect to <blog-ip> port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to <blog-ip> port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <blog-ip> port 80: Connection refused
```

Interestingly, running `curl` or `ping` from my local machine works just fine, but the wordpress server becomes curl-invisible to **mydomain** server. The only way to stop *Bad Gateway* is to change `WORDPRESS_URL` and `SITE_URL` back to the server's IP and even then, it again only starts working after some time.

I am completely clueless about what is going on. Both servers are Digital Ocean droplets. I had issues before with undocumented blocks on their side (they do not allow sending email from a Droplet by default, so you have to contact support for that) and wondered if it is not the case. Their support, however, doesn't seem to know what is happening either, so I decided to try and post the question here.

Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated.